# How to get around nop_streaming_read error : Resource temporarily unavailable in mplayer?

Tags: mplayer

I am trying to capture a stream using `mplayer` using the `-dumpstream` option:

```
mplayer -dumpstream mms://<url> -dumpfile out.wmv
```

But I'm always getting this error after several tens of megabytes:

```
nop_streaming_read error : Resource temporarily unavailable
```

I'm connected by wireless, but I still think it's reasonable to expect to be able to capture a whole stream...

The general advice on the internet for this problem is to retry the capture. However, I have been retrying automatically using a script, and it's been running more than three days now, always restarting due to this error.

Another thing I tried is checking out [mplayer from svn](http://svn://svn.mplayerhq.hu/mplayer/trunk), changing `to = 10 * 1000` to `to = 600 * 1000` in `stream/tcp.c`, compiling and using this `mplayer`. It should have increased the timeout to 10 minutes, I think. However, I still see this problem.